# splash screen issue with android + phonegap

Tags: html, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, splash-screen

i am working with phonegap+sencha touch application.

I have added a splash screen in android as follow,

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

then i have set Autohidesplashscreen property to false as follow in config.xml,

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

**still it hide automatically after some seconds**, i want to make splash screen visible for some second as i want. 
is there any solution for this ? 
any help will be appreciated. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity.java, you can set a timer value in your super.loadUrl() method. Like this:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",10000);
```

This will show Splashscreen for 10 seconds. You can increase the value as you wish.

Comment: i have already use this, but i want to load both splash screen and index.html at a same time and after some seconds i want to hide splash screen, is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps and let me know if it works for you:

**1)** Find/add the following tag to your config.xml file under www folder;

In the config.xml: `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000">`

**2)** Change the value to a greater number (e.g 10000). Beware that the number is in ms;

**3)** Make sure you have the Splash screen plugin installed (**org.apache.cordova.splashscreen**). You can check by going to your folder and executing the following command on terminal:

**Phonegap**: `phonegap local plugin list`

**Cordova**: `cordova plugin list`

**4)** If you don't have the plugin, add it by using the following command:

**Phonegap**: `phonegap local add plugin org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`

**Cordova**: `cordova add plugin org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`

**5)** In your JavaScript code you can add the following code to close the splash screen:

```
    //checks for splashscreen and hides it
    if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {    
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
```

**PS: All Terminal commands were tested in MacOSX 10.8 using the terminal, and using Phonegap 3.4. All terminal commands must be executed from withing the application folder**